# SystemJS - Is the jspm_packages folder supposed to be copied to dist and sent to the server?

Tags: jspm, systemjs

I'm new to SystemJs and jspm, and I'm working on creating a build process.

Is the `jspm_packages` supposed to be sent to `dist` and then the server?

I'm confused about that. My first impression is that it isn't, but after working with SystemJs and jspm for a while I've noticed a couple of things.

- The sourcemaps point to the `jspm_pcakages` folder.
- The paths inside of the CSS files imported with the [css-plugin](https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-css) also refer to that folder (think of fonts, images, etc.)

Having those points in mind, I've thought that maybe the idea behind that folder is to be sent to the server after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, jspm_packages is supposed to be sent to the server unless you create an sfx- bundle for production. Alternatively, you can point SystemJS to fetch modules from a CDN so that you don't need to host jspm_packages yourself.

Read more about Production workflows here: https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/blob/master/docs/production-workflows.md

P.S. It's likely that you don't want to have source maps in production. So the only problem is css. You can inject it into the bundle as well: https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-css#builder-support

Comment: Thanks! At first it seeemed strange to me, as I would not send a `bower_components` folder to the server.

Comment: I am interested in preserving the sourcemaps for production too, I think they can be useful for debugging stuff on production. Apart from that, even if you inject the CSS, you will still need the fonts and images that that CSS references. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You can also run `jspm install` on the server. What I meant is that the `jspm_packages` should be on the server in one or another way. Unless you create a bundle or host stuff on a CDN.